# Service Fabric Reliable Service with WCF communication

Tags: c#, wcf, azure-service-fabric

I haven't had much luck finding an example of a Stateful Reliable Service using the WCFCommunicationListener. I guess my disconnect is where you implement the Operation Contracts. Is it done in the main service class? You can't add an svc file to the Service, so I assume it has to be some other class that is triggered when the client calls the WCFCommunicationListener.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it's done programmatically on the main service class. Should be fairly simple to do if you follow this doc: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-reliable-services-communication-wcf/

Basically just this:

```
[ServiceContract]
interface IAdderWcfContract
{
    //
    // Adds the input to the value stored in the service and returns the result.
    //
    [OperationContract]
    Task<double> AddValue(double input);

    //
    // Resets the value stored in the service to zero.
    //
    [OperationContract]
    Task ResetValue();

    //
    // Reads the currently stored value.
    //
    [OperationContract]
    Task<double> ReadValue();
}

class MyService: StatefulService, IAdderWcfContract
{
    ...
    CreateServiceReplicaListeners()
    {
        return new[] { new ServiceReplicaListener((context) =>
            new WcfCommunicationListener<IAdderWcfContract>(
                wcfServiceObject:this,
                serviceContext:context,
                //
                // The name of the endpoint configured in the ServiceManifest under the Endpoints section
                // that identifies the endpoint that the WCF ServiceHost should listen on.
                //
                endpointResourceName: "WcfServiceEndpoint",

                //
                // Populate the binding information that you want the service to use.
                //
                listenerBinding: WcfUtility.CreateTcpListenerBinding()
            )
        )};
    } 

    // implement service methods
    ...
}
```

Comment: Yeah. I figured this out after I posted. Thanks for the good answer though!